# ternary quadratic forms over polynomial rings

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

The following theorem by Legendre is well-known:
The integral ternary quadratic form $f(x,y,z) = ax^2 + by^2 +cz^2 \in {\bf Z}[x]$ represents $0$ non-trivially if and only if

1. $a$, $b$, and $c$ do not have the same sign.
2. $-bc$ is a quadratic residue $\rm mod|a|$, $-ca$ is a quadratic residue $\rm mod|b|$, and $-ab$ is a quadratic residue $\rm mod|c|$.

My question: Is an analogous theorem true if we replace $\bf Z$ by polynomial rings? Like ${\bf Z}[t]$ (so that $a(t)$, $b(t)$, $c(t)$ are polynomials with integral coefficients as are $x(t)$, $y(t)$, and $z(t)$) or by ${\bf F}_q[t]$ where ${\bf F}_q$ is the finite field of cardinality $q$? Does anyone know of a reference where this theorem has been proved? Thanks!

Comment: you want the book Basic Quadratic Forms by Larry Gerstein. He has published a fair amount  on quadratic forms with coefficients in the rings you mention. I have the book, I will see what there might be on ternaries.

Comment: He gives a summary in section 10.3. For details, he refers to Number Theory in Function Fields by M. Rosen  http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b14271769~S1

Comment: I have Rosen's book and Ireland & Rosen my favorites, and I found a copy of Gerstein's book which looks soo good!!